# Apache axis 2 asking for credentials when URL is entered

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, webservice-client

I am writing a web service client in Eclipse through Apache Axis 2 client. I enter the URL it is asking for credentials.
Though I gave valid credentials, it is not accepting.

What could be the exact reason for this?

Comment: What server do you try to connect to? How did you give "valid credentials"?

Comment: @AaronDigulla.This server is Apache CFX server. It prompted me for credentials through popup to enter username and password.

Comment: I somehow doubt that it did. The code generated by Axis2 doesn't support a UI, so it can't ask you with a popup. There is either vital information which you are withholding or a cracker just got your login...

Answer (score 0):

Check the C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\conf\tomcat-users.xml for valid credentials under the user tag